# Comparing multiple variables to one string (at once)

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any neater way (than presented below) to encode multiple AND comparison?

```
If a = "Not identified" And _
     b = "Not identified" And _
     c = "Not identified" And _
     c = "Not identified" And _
     d = "Not identified" And _
     e = "Not identified" And _
     f = "Not identified" And _
     g = "Not identified" Then
```

I have tried to google this for 20 minutes and found nothing. I expect a logical comparison encoded in one - two lines of code. Something like:

```
If WorksheetFunction.TextJoin("", True, a, b, c, d, e) = WorksheetFunction.Rept("Not identified", 5) Then
```

Comment: instead of multiple variables use a string array and loop through them setting a Boolean to false and breaking out of the loop when any item doesn't match.

Comment: Where from did you extract `a` to `g`? Are they in a range? Are they in an array?

Comment: @FaneDuru - those are multiple cells' values

Comment: Arn't they consecutive? On a row or a column?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, they are. It's a Range("C80:C87")

Comment: Then, no need of any iteration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
Dim rng As Range, strText As String
   
   strText = "Not identified"
   Set rng = Range("C80:C87")
   If rng.cells.count = _
       WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, strText) Then Debug.Print "OK"
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your solution checks if any of strings in range = "Not identified" which would be an equivalent of "OR" comparison. I am looking for an equivalent of "AND" comparison.

Comment: @Dominik Dusza What do you really want accomplishing? Forget about `And` for this very moment... Do you want checking if **all involved cells contain "Not identified" string**? If not, please better explain your need, not the way you think is appropriate... I tried only showing a way to identify such a string in a range.

Comment: Do you want checking if all involved cells contain "Not identified" string? - YES.  
In my original inquiry I have posted a portion of code which is perfectly fine (the one with multiple ANDs). All I want to do is to write the same thing in a neater way.

Comment: @Dominik Dusza OK. I will post a code line doing that... Replacing the part identifying if the string exists.